# Display omitted versions in maven dependency:tree?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

In Eclipse, when I go to the Maven Dependency Hierarchy page, I get output that states what conflicts caused versions to be omitted:

[image: eclipse maven version]

However, if I use [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html), that's omitted and I only see the evrsions which are actually used:

```
|  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
|  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
```

And later on the actually referenced versions...

```
+- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
```

Is there any way to get dependency:tree to output the versions omitted for conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can have the omitted artifacts by setting the [`verbose`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#verbose) attribute to `true`:

> Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency tree.

This attribute defaults to `false`. On the command line, you would have

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true
```

Comment: This only works until dependency plugin version 3.0. With 3.1, you have to use option -X. But then you still do not see omitted dependencies. What do I need to do then?

Comment: The only option I've found is to use an older version of dependency plugin: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true`. There's a warning though: `Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution`. It's still better than nothing.

Comment: For me, `-Dverbose` does work in Maven 3.6. But it does not work together with `-DoutputType=dot`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use the [depgraph-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin).

- to see all dependencies, set `showDuplicates` to true

  - this will include dependencies that `dependency:tree` would show with `verbose` option
- to see conflicts, set `showConflicts` to true
- has various filters to include/exclude projects
- can export to various formats, including dot file that can be rendered with GraphViz

  - I use vscode plugin [GraphViz Interactive Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.graphviz-interactive-preview) to render and view dot files.

Example config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ferstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>depgraph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <showDuplicates>true</showDuplicates>
        <showConflicts>true</showConflicts>
        <includes>
            <!-- groupId:artifactId:type:classifier -->
            <include>com.mycompany*:*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run `mvn depgraph:graph` in your project to find a new file in `target/dependency-graph.dot`.

Note that you can include the plugin with scope `provided` such that it will not be included in any build artifact.

Comment: Just a little addition: If you want to quickly analyse your module dependencies (without adding the plugin to your project), just run `mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:3.3.0:graph -DrepeatTransitiveDependenciesInTextGraph -DshowVersions -DgraphFormat=text  -DshowGroupIds -DshowConflicts -DshowDuplicates` in the folder of your module.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), the `-Dverbose=true` argument is ignored in versions 3.0 of the plugin and above. You need to use an older version; the above link suggests the following (works for me):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true
```