# Maven: find usage of dependency by dependencies?

Tags: maven

My project, `com.example.foo`, uses dependency `com.example.bar`. But it also uses `com.example.baz`, which in turn also uses `com.example.bar`.

When I run `mvn dependency:tree`, I get something like

```
com.example.foo
+- com.example.bar
\- com.example.baz
```

**Question:** How can I have maven repeat the dependency on `bar` in its output, like so (respecting any filter options I set, like `-Dincludes=com.example.*`):

```
com.example.foo
+- com.example.bar
\- com.example.baz
   \- com.example.bar
```

Comment: Can you try with `-Dverbose=true` like stated here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35588983/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki That's it! Do you want to post that as a proper answer, so you can have the points you deserve? ;-) (I had tried `-X` elsewhere, but the debug output is a bit too much... Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.)

Comment: Great that it works for you! It would be better to mark as duplicate, so as not to repeat the answer. I have voted it as such, you could accept it by clicking a button on top of your question :)!