# How to find a dependency in maven, dependency:tree doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

In a effective pom I see

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-site</id>
        <phase>site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>site</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/tatiana/repos/selenium-tests/masbuilder-tests/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-deploy</id>
        <phase>site-deploy</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/tatiana/repos/selenium-tests/masbuilder-tests/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>/home/tatiana/repos/selenium-tests/masbuilder-tests/target/site</outputDirectory>
      <reportPlugins>
        <reportPlugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        </reportPlugin>
      </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But I don't use maven-site-plugin and when I execute 
    mvn dependency:tree

then I don't see any mention of maven-site-plugin or "site" keyword or maven-project-info-reports-plugin in output.

The same for 
    mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

The problem is error in effective POM which I would like to remove:
*element reportplugins is not allowed here*

Maybe it is related *with maven-surefire-plugin* which I use?

Comment: Are you sure that some library that you use doesn't have a transitive dependency on the maven-site-plugin?

Comment: How to check/to see it? I 've tried to use  
     mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose 

without success (see dependencies but not this)

Comment: It sounds you are inherit this from some of your parents you are using..?

Comment: I don't think so, how to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

If dependency is already present with the higher version in the tree,  then all jruby-complete's dependencies are listed at shallower depth in tree, because dependency tree mojo prunes lower level dependencies.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` to show the ommitted dependencies.

Comment: verbose might not work with Maven 3: "Notice this feature actually uses Maven 2 algorithm and may give wrong results when used with Maven 3"

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

verbose might not work for Maven 3. There is also another [solution from different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68101756/11817936) by using  [depgraph-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin):

> mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:3.3.0:graph -DrepeatTransitiveDependenciesInTextGraph -DshowVersions -DgraphFormat=text  -DshowGroupIds -DshowConflicts -DshowDuplicates