# Why does my war file contain a dependency not in my tree?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have an app that I build with maven.

First, I run `mvn clean`.

Then, after I build it, I'm finding that I get 2 copies of the `jackson-databind` jar:

```
ls target/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib | grep jackson
jackson-annotations-2.8.9.jar
jackson-core-2.8.9.jar
jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar
```

However, when I run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I only see reference to

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.9:compile
```

Even if I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`, there's no sign of 2.4.4 in the tree

What gives? Am I misunderstanding the report, because we're clearly pulling in 2.4.4 for *some* reason?

Put another way (to keep this less broad), how can maven be pulling in a dependency that isn't listed in the dependency tree?

Comment: What do you see when you run the command with the [verbose](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#verbose) flag set to `true`? (`-Dverbose=true`)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588952/display-omitted-versions-in-maven-dependencytree

Comment: Did you run `mvn clean` to make sure no old dependencies are there from earlier builds?

Comment: Yes (question updated)

Comment: If you haven't found a clue of the other than there is something different wrong...Please show your pom file...make `mvn clean package` make an `unzip -t XYZ.war` and take a look there if the other versions are there...Without the real project it's hard to find the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the rogue file is a WAR dependency, not a JAR dependency.

I don't believe these are visible on the tree because they are not 'resolved', per se... they are just copied over.

Doing

```
find target/ -name jackson-databind-\*.jar
```

Lists them all. They show up in the `target/war/work` directory which gives you a pointer to where they are coming from.

Excluding them needs to be done in the configuration of the `maven-war-plugin`:

```
<configuration>                                                           
    <overlays>                                                            
        <overlay>                                                         
            <groupId>com.group</groupId>                                 
            <artifactId>artifact-you-depend-on</artifactId>                 
            <excludes>                                                    
                <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar</exclude> 
            </excludes>                                                   
        </overlay>                                                        
    </overlays>                                                           
</configuration>
```

Comment: Wrong way. Better is to give them scope: provided...manual excludes is a smell...

Comment: Yeah... the dependency is pretty smelly, but I don't own it