# Enhancing Log4J2 Version in SpringBoot App

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, log4j2

Trying to use a latest version of Log4J2 version 2.10 in a Spring Boot APP.

Ours is a Micro service solution, hence to start with created a reusable module with below mentioned  details -

Reusable Log Component (POM fragments as follows)-

```
    <log4j.version>2.10.0</log4j.version>
    <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The microService project then refers to it as -

```
     <log4j.version>2.10.0</log4j.version>
    <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>reusable-logger-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Irrespective of overriding the jar version to 2.10.0, it shows 2.7.0 -

[image]
Question 1 -> Is this normal?

My work around was to include below jars into the MicroService's POM file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>reusable-logger-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Question 2) Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to include/override the log4j2's version in the micro service's POM-

```
      <properties>
            <log4j2.version>
                   2.10.0
            </log4j2.version>
      </properties>
```

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.
>   "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies, eg. if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In your microService module, spring-boot-starter requested version 2.7, but your reusable-logger-starter requested 2.10.0. Maven decided 2.10.

See [Interpreting "omitted for conflict" in maven 2 dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742312/interpreting-omitted-for-conflict-in-maven-2-dependency-tree)

The simple answer to Question 2 is: Yes, people have faced this behavior.

What you should maybe ask is how to solve this, read about Maven BOMs for guidance.