# Issue with mvn dependency versions

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a jar A(version 1.2) which is using 1.4.6 version of jar B.the mvn dependency:tree is showing 1.4.6 version of jar B only.
Now, I use this jar A version 1.2 in jar C and do mvn dependency:tree, I get 1.2.6 version of jar B.
I am wondering how is this possible ?

```
[INFO] A:jar:1.2
[INFO] \- B:jar:1.4.6:compile


[INFO] C:jar:1.0.9
[INFO] \- A:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]   \- B:jar:1.2.6:compile
```

Kindly suggest how is this happening?

Comment: That's not an issue it's working as designed. If you like to force to use a particular versions there are two options. One change Project A should use a newer version... and the other is to define the version in dependencyMangement in project C...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen if

1. C (or one of its parents) has a `<dependencyManagement>` section that enforces a specific version of B,
2. C has a direct dependency on B:jar:1.2.6,
3. C has also another transitive dependency on B (specifically on B:jar:1.2.6) that [takes precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742312/685806) over the one inherited from A.

Note that version 2.x of the dependency plugin was capable of showing this information with messages like "version managed from x.x.x" or "omitted for conflict" (see [Display omitted versions in maven dependency:tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35588952/685806)).  The "Dependency Hierarchy" tab in Eclipse still shows this information.